# How to preserve docker cache on disconnected systems?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Synopsis. A remote instance gets connected to the Internet via satellite modem when technician visits the cabin. Technician setups the application stack via `docker compose` and leaves the location. The location has no internet connection and periodically loses electricity (once in a few days).
The application stack is typical, like mysql + nodejs. And it is used by "polar bears". I mean nobody, it is a monitoring app.

How to ensure that docker images will be persisted for an undefined amount of time and the compose stack survives through endless reboots?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no real easy solution.

But with a little bit of `yq` magic to parse `docker-compose.yaml` and `docker save`  command it is possible to store the images locally to a specific location.

Then we can add startup script to import these images using `docker load` into the local docker cache.